# Unable to make a new deployment on google apps script project

Tags: google-apps-script

It's been a couple of days since I am unable to make new deployments when working on a google apps script project. Earlier to this I was able to do many deployments per day. Now, whenever I attend to do a new one the loading indicator stays on forever. Any idea where I could find support for such an issue?

[image]

EDIT: I noticed the following error on the console whenever clicking on a deploy button
[image]

Comment: Have you tested doing it using a different account, a different browser, or a different network? Are you using a gmail.com or a Google Workspace account?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, tried all 3 of them, unfortunately the result is the same. I'm using a gmail account. Will try the google workspace one...

Comment: is the google workspace account a paid service?

Comment: Yes, Google Workspace is a paid Google service. Have you tested by sharing the script with someone else and attempt to do the deployment from the other account? Do you get the same error if you try to do a deployment from a new script file?

Comment: Yes, I shared the project to another gmail account, then used another browser to access the other account, loaded the project but got the same error. I also tried renaming my main code file, no changes there as well.
This deploy menu has 3 buttons underneath it and I noticed that whenever I hit any of them I get a javascript console error on a Array.sort method, could this be the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Did you make the test of copying your code in a new Apps Script file and try to make a deployment there? [This](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/XySto_NmaTY) seems to be the same behavior

Comment: Thanks for the link, I created a new project, copied everything over and now deployments are fine. Please post an answer to give you the credits.

Comment: I am glad to hear that helped. Added the answer as requested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to a possible Apps Script bug. According to [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/XySto_NmaTY) the solution would be to create a new script file in Apps Script and try to make a new deployment from there.

According to [this other Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-apps-script-community/c/udnJCTYEU18) a possible solution is to enable the Google Apps Script API within the current project.

In this case from the comments section we have confirmed that the issue was resolved by creating the deployment in a new Apps Script file, however it could be reported to Google using the Google Issue Tracker, or if you have a Google Workspace account you could open a support ticket for further investigation.

#### References:

- [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried recreating the files in a new project and enabling the Google Apps Script API as suggested above, and neither worked. I created a completely clean project and it *did* deploy successfully, so I copied my project over piece by piece. The issue was with my `appsscript.json` file. Specifically, the version of a library was a number:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": ...,
        "version": 123,
        "libraryId": ...
      }
    ]
  },
 
  ...
}
```

Changing it to a string seemed to fix the issue:
`"version": "123"`.

I'm 99% sure I didn't write this code and it was auto-generated by Apps Script when I clicked "Add a library". Oh well...